# cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'mvc:annotation-driven' error

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have added the spring-security-config-3.1.0.RC3.jar in my lib folder and i still get this error. What can be possible reason ??

Here is my dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

   <context:component-scan base-package="com.tcs.rspm.controller" />
<mvc:annotation-driven /> 
   <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix" value="/webpages/" />
      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
   </bean>

</beans>
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You have this:

```
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
```

but you're not mentioning it here:

```
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
```

To fix that, you should have

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
```

there as well, like

```
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
```

Note: it is actually common that schema references don't mention Spring version to allow for easier upgrading, so you should use references like `http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd` instead of the ones having `-3.0` in the name.

Comment: I got similiar error for <mvc:cors /> annotation. When I remove version part of schema urls the error in xml file (eclipse) disappears but tomcat can't start, giving the same error. Where can I check where is the mvc:cors and what should add in xmlns and schemaLocation?

Comment: I found that Spring 4.2 has the first support for CORS, version update solved my problem.

Answer (score -1):

I had an almost similar error as you. My applicationContext.xml file was like this :

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd

http://www.springframework.org/schema/context

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">//should be context instead of beans
```

When I had tried to write

`<context:property-placeholder location="file:src/application.properties"/>`

then I got error.I fixed the error by copying the code which is below :

```
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
```